# How come "items" is required=false for standart tag c:forEach?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

So this is from c.tld, Tag Library Descriptior for JSTL tags starting with

```
<tag>
    <description>
        The basic iteration tag, accepting many different
        collection types and supporting subsetting and other
        functionality
    </description>
    <name>forEach</name>
    <tag-class>org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForEachTag</tag-class>
    <tei-class>org.apache.taglibs.standard.tei.ForEachTEI</tei-class>
    <body-content>JSP</body-content>
    <attribute>
        <description>
            Collection of items to iterate over.
        </description>
        <name>items</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        <type>java.lang.Object</type>
        <deferred-value>
            <type>java.lang.Object</type>
        </deferred-value>
    </attribute>
```

My question is, how can I use forEach without "items" ? Why is it required=false?

This is how it can be used with items:

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.songs}" var="song">
    Song: ${song}
    <br />
</c:forEach>
```

as an example..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the other attributes available on the forEach tag to form a simple counter, without having a specific array of values to iterate over, e.g.:

```
<p>The numbers from one to 10 are:</p>
<ul>
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="10">
   <li><c:out value="${i}"/></li>
</c:forEach>
</ul>
```

This could be quite useful with the `step` attribute too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it with out items .. like below

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5">
Item <c:out value="${i}"/><p>
</c:forEach>
```